# Android Studio Progress Bar

Tags: android

I have been stuck on this for almost a week . I am trying to make my progress bar go into the second activity when it is done loading . I posted this before but nobody has helped me. When the progress bar is done loading(When it gets to 100) i want it to start activity 2 . But I changed the code  A LOT of times and it's still not working. I'm not getting any type of errors or anything , it's just not working . So can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong or give me code ? I would appreciate it very very very much !

MainActivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private ImageView ImageView;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private int progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 5;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class progressBar extends ProgressBar {

    progressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public progressBar(Context context) { super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if (progress == this.getMax()) {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Just in case it's relevant android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.brandon.territories" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If you know the problem or code please tell me . Thanks !

Comment: have you tried broadcast receiver ?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the condition for start the second activity in the run method of your handler.
Like this:

```
if(progressBar.getMax() == progressStatus) {
// start the activity here 
}
```

You need to change the condition of your while statement too:

```
while(progressStatus <= progressBar.getMax())
```

***EDIT:***

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"/>
```

Comment: Not working and when i put in the while statement i get errors

Comment: How do i set getMax() ? How does android know what the getMax is ?

Comment: You have to define the max in the xml of your progressBar. You can set, for instance: `android:max="100"`. If you dont set max the progress will not work.

Comment: Remove this from SecondActivity in Manifest:
 `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>`

Comment: I honestly can't find any type of errors in this code . Nothing is red

Comment: I cleaned it a lot of times and it's still not working .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you use your custom ProgressBar? I noticed that you cast

```
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

But you have your own class "progressBar" in which you start another activity  (you should name it different, as you extend ProgressBar, and class name must starts from Capital letter, "MyProgressBar" ). Also you should have your ProgressBar defined in layout of your activity:

```
   <com.example.brandon.territories.MainActivity.MyProgressBar
   android:id="@id/progressBar"
   ....
   </com.example.brandon.territories.MainActivity.MyProgressBar>
```

But it's convenient to define your progress bar class in separate file.

Comment: It's define in activitty_main file